# Need Solution : OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: pandas, google-analytics, anaconda, data-science

**import pandas as pd**

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)  in 
----> 1 import pandas as pd

```
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
      9 for dependency in hard_dependencies:
     10     try:
---> 11         __import__(dependency)
     12     except ImportError as e:
     13         missing_dependencies.append(f"{dependency}: {e}")

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    136 
    137     # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 138     from . import _distributor_init
    139 
    140     from . import core

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
     24                 # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL
     25                 # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?
---> 26                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     27                 DLL_filenames.append(filename)
     28         if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:

~\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    379 
    380         if handle is None:
--> 381             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    382         else:
    383             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: You have an interaction between a python installation at `~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38` and your anaconda installation. Would it be an option to just uninstall the version sitting at `~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38`?

Comment: I tried but I still facing the same issue

Comment: Can you post the new Traceback?

Comment: ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py

I reinstalled python after uninstalling the previous one.

Comment: That was not the point of my suggestion. You already have anaconda python, so I suggested to uninstall the other python installation and keep it deleted

Comment: Ok, You mean I just keep one tool which is Anaconda. Right!

Comment: Yes, that was my suggestion

Comment: No, Didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer:

You just need to delete the `Python` Folder from `AppData`.

It's worked for me.